# Update field of a firebase key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure in the firebase with some keys, I would like to know how to update a field of the last key generated. 
I need to retrieve the last key generated and update the data, how to do that ???

[image: Image of the database]

### In Json format

What I would like to change "Status"

```
   "-Kuxu1dX_aMcKZbqpGiQ" : {
    "Status" : {
      "status" : "Engano"
    },
    "data" : "26/9/2017 às 8h17",
    "funcionario" : "João Cardoso",
    "motivo" : "Carta",
    "nome" : "Felipe Antunes",
    "tempo" : -1506424666540,
    "visita" : "null"
  },
  "-KuxuQuZzcTV5T-PHw18" : {
    "Status" : {
      "status" : "Engano"
    },
    "data" : "26/9/2017 às 8h19",
    "funcionario" : "João Cardoso",
    "motivo" : "Encomenda",
    "nome" : "Felipe Antunes",
    "tempo" : -1506424770025,
    "visita" : "null"
  }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I already put the json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to make a change to an item, you'll first need to find that item with a query:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("7VCZ8oJSz...");
Query query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            childSnapshot.getRef().getChild("Status").setValue("New value");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Query:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I get the reference of the last generated key?

Comment: That's what `childSnapshot.getRef()` does.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("7VCZ8oJSz...");
Query query = yourRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        dataSnapshot.child("Status").child("status").setValue("yourNewValue");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I get the reference of the last generated key?